# Can I point my zone apex (example.com versus www.example.com) at my website hosted on an another cloud platform (not Amazon)?

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, cname-record, amazon-route53

I'm stuck with a problem I guess many of you suffered before and I'm trying to solve it my way without moving from Amazon Route 53 DNS services to another DNS provider.

I host two applications in two different cloud platforms (one private cloud platform and Windows Azure) and I have the same scenario in both.

Basically, I need to map my domain (let's say foo.com) to foo.cloudapp.net as well as www.foo.com to foo.cloudapp.net. The problem is that Amazon only let you do that if you host your application in their servers and not in others (you can see FAQ questions starting with "Can I point my zone apex (example.com versus www.example.com) ..." being answered with a Yes!). Well, my question should be the next question on the FAQ and by now is being answered with a No. I read several answers on the internet saying that if they do that they wouldn't be following DNS spec but they DO NOT follow the Spec if you host on Amazon so my question: what do I have to do to solve this issue about mapping the Zone apex to a CNAME or URL not to an IP as nowadays almost no one uses IP addresses.

I know that I can move to another DNS servers and then problem solve! but I found none of the services charge you by month and as cheap and user friendly and secure as Amazon...

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.wwwizer.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RFC1033` indeed doesn't allow for a zone apex to be a `CNAME` record. And `Route53` seems to be `RFC1033` compliant. However, there are other services (even free services) that wipe their behinds with this `RFC1033` requirement, enabling you to do what you're trying to do. I know for a fact [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/dns) offers DNS hosting as a free service and they allow for the zone apex to be a `CNAME`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the link to CloudFare. I will check if CloudFare supports also wildarding CNAME as I also need that. Anyway, I'm not sure if Route53 is RFC1033 compliant as they offer and "alias" service (so exactly the same as what CNAME is) for their products in the Apex zone. So, from my perspective, they are not RFC1033 as CNAME is not supported for external products but it is supported for their products like hosting in EC2 as you can see [in their FAQs](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/#Zone_apex) and in the next two questions.

Comment: Cloudflare supports a wildcard `CNAME` entry. And as for the alias DNS entries: they're not `CNAME` entries. They're actually `A` records with a -very- low ttl (of 60 seconds) mapping to an IP address (e.g. one of the IP addresses of your loadbalancer). When the DNS server receives a request for your alias record, it picks an IP address from the ELB pool. This makes it `RFC1033` compliant.